# What is the correct way to create preset Structs?

Tags: swift

In Swift classes we can use a `class function` to create preset instances. Like the calendar example below:

```
let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
```

Which will have a similar pattern as this :

```
class SomeClass {

    var attribute : String

    init(value:String) {
        attribute = value
    }

    class func testClass() -> SomeClass {
        return SomeClass(value: "test")
    }
}

let test = SomeClass.testClass()
```

But there are no class functions in structs obviously. Xcode recommends using `static` instead. This is very close to the singleton pattern.

```
struct SomeStruct {

    var attribute : String

    init(value:String) {
        attribute = value
    }
    static var testStruct = SomeStruct(value: "test")
}
```

Singleton pattern

```
class Singleton {

    static let shared = Singleton()

    private init() {

    }
}
```

So is this an ok way to init a struct with preset values since structs are value types. If it is not ok, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `class func` for struct types is `static func`:

```
static func testStruct() -> SomeStruct {
    return SomeStruct(value: "foo")
}
```

and a static property (the "singleton-pattern") works identically
with both class and struct types:

```
static let singleStruct = SomeStruct(value: "foo")
```

`testStruct()` creates a value on each call, whereas `singleStruct`
creates the value once (on the first call).

In most cases that would make no difference because structures are
value types. The static property has advantages if creating the
value is "expensive". Also, as @Lance noticed in a comment,
this pattern is used by Apple frequently, such as `CGRect.zero`.

However, it makes a difference if the struct has properties which
are reference types (or pointers to unmanaged memory). Here is an example:

```
class MyClass {
    var attribute : String
    init(value : String) {
        attribute = value
    }
}

struct SomeStruct {

    var ptr : MyClass

    init(value : String) {
        ptr = MyClass(value: value)
    }
    static func testStruct() -> SomeStruct {
        return SomeStruct(value: "foo")
    }

    static let singleStruct = SomeStruct(value: "foo")
}
```

*Using the static function:*

```
let test1 = SomeStruct.testStruct()
print(test1.ptr.attribute) // foo

let test2 = SomeStruct.testStruct()
test2.ptr.attribute = "bar"

print(test1.ptr.attribute) // foo
```

Here `test1` and `test2` are separate values and we get the expected
output.

*Using the static property:*

```
let test1 = SomeStruct.singleStruct
print(test1.ptr.attribute) // foo

let test2 = SomeStruct.singleStruct
test2.ptr.attribute = "bar"

print(test1.ptr.attribute) // bar  <--- What?
```

Here, `test1` and `test2` are set to the same value returned from
the static property. Changing `test2.ptr` does *not mutate* `test2`,
resulting in the somewhat unexpected output for `test1.ptr.attribute`

See [Friday Q&A 2015-04-17: Let's Build Swift.Array](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-04-17-lets-build-swiftarray.html) for an interesting article on how this can be solved.

---

Btw, `static` can be used with class types as well, here `static`
is a shortcut for `class final`: a type method that cannot be overridden
in a subclass. Since there is no inheritance for struct types it makes
sense that type methods for struct types are written as `static`.

Comment: does it needs to be a `static function` or can it also be a `static` `var` or `let`. I have now used `static functions`. It seemed better but I could not really give a reason for it, since Struct are value types and copy anyway.

Comment: Never mind. I just realised that if you implement it as an attribute every preset would have an instance of every other preset also. Even if they are lazy, there is really no need.

Comment: @RMenke: Actually I think you were right, `static let testStruct = SomeStruct(value: "test")` would have exactly the same result for value types.

Comment: I think I will keep using the `static functions` Somehow it feels wrong to have a bunch of attributes to generate presets. Making it a function makes the purpose clearer.

Comment: if you look at CGRect in Swift, you'll see that `zero`, `null`, and `infinite` are all `static var`s. I would say that is a good way to go since Apple is doing it.

Comment: @Lance: Usually yes. But if the struct has properties which are reference types (or pointers) then it makes a difference. I'm going to update the answer ...

Comment: @RMenke: I have re-written the answer (partially in response to Lance's comment), hopefully that makes sense now.

Comment: Yup the difference is crystal clear! thank you! @Lance good catch!